# Try except inside a function doesn't work but outside does

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, try-catch

I'm trying to get the `try except`  block outside of my function as a part of DRY. If I put it directly into the function it works

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def user_info(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        username = request.GET.get("username")
        password = request.GET.get("password")

    try:
        Account.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({
            "success": "false",
            "error_code": "1",
        })
```

But if I make it into function `user_check` it doesn't work

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def user_info(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        username = request.GET.get("username")
        password = request.GET.get("password")

        user_check(username,password)
```

```
def user_check(username,password):
    try:
        Account.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({
            "success": "false",
            "error_code": "1",
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Return from try block too. Like:

```
def user_check(username,password):
    try:
        Account.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
        # Add this line
        return True
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({
            "success": "false",
            "error_code": "1",
        })
```

And, your function could be:

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def user_info(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        username = request.GET.get("username")
        password = request.GET.get("password")

        data = user_check(username, password)
        if data==True:
            # executed from try block known
```

Comment: this doesn't work too because except doesn't return the JsonResponse but <Response status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">